# Remove overlapping red and green color

Tags: graphics, image-processing, color

How to remove overlapping red and green color regions, leaving only red ones?

[image]

Comment: [`ImageApply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageApply.html) might be useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This removes the "overlapping" areas, assuming the green area doesn't have holes exactly where the red is, leaving the red areas only outside the green area:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSBJW.png"]
{r, g, b, alpha} = ColorSeparate[img];
n = Image[0*ImageData[r]];
rnew = ImageMultiply[ColorNegate@Closing[Binarize[g], 4], r]
ColorCombine[{rnew, n, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This code simply removes the green:

```
rnew2 = ImageMultiply[ColorNegate@Binarize[g], r]
ColorCombine[{rnew2, n, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]